# Java convention on reference to methods and variables

Tags: java, object, coding-style, naming-conventions

Section 10.2 of Java conventions recommends using class names instead of objects to use static variables or methods, i.e. `MyClass.variable1` or `MyClass.methodName1()` instead of

```
MyClass Obj1 = new MyClass();    
Obj1.variable1;
Obj1.methodName1();
```

There is no explanation of the rationale behind this, although I suspect this has something to do with memory use. It would be great if someone could explain this.

Comment: If the method is static, call it from the class itself - it's less confusing. e.g. `BigInteger.ONE.valueOf("10")` is confusing to what its actually being done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you mean "for static methods and variables".

There is no difference regarding memory, except of course if you create the instance just for calling the method. Conventions aren't for memory efficiency but for coder efficiency, which is directly related with the readability of the code.

The rationale is that by reading

```
MyClass.methodName1()
```

you know it's a static method and that it can't use or change your `Obj1` instance.

And if you write

```
obj1.variable1; // note the "o" instead of "O", please do follow conventions
```

then the reader has to read your source code to know if variable1 is static or not.

Comment: Interesting post about why it can be confusing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1439847/829571

Comment: @assylias Interesting example, yes.

Comment: @dystroy: thanks, so the main idea is to know straight away, if the variable or method is static.

Answer (score 3):

If you use object for static variable access then compiler will replace it with `Class Name` only.

So

```
MyClass Obj1 = new MyClass();    
Obj1.variable1;
Obj1.methodName1();
```

It is same as

```
MyClass.variable1;
MyClass.methodName1();
```

`Now Why to differentiate? Answer is - It is for better reading If someone see method being called on Class then he immediately come to know that it is static method. Also it prevents generation of one additional object to access the method.`

Comment: But the first version will in general call MyClass' <init>. I don't know whether the compiler really optimizes this away, if init is trivial.

Comment: @HeikoSchmitz ["When the compiler compiles that class it decides at compile time which exact method is called for each static method call (that's the big difference to non-static method calls: the exact method to be called is only decided at runtime in those cases"](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1253445)

Comment: That's clear. However, my point is that the first version includes constructing a MyClass instance (including ctor, initializer, etc), which can have side-effects and, thus, is not the same as the second version, where no object is generated.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with `public` `static` methods and variables. Since these methods/variables are associated with the respective class rather than an instance of the class, it is nice to use refer to these methods or variables as `className.methodName()` or `className.variableName`

["Understanding Instance and Class Members"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) would be a good starting point to learn about the use of the static keyword to create fields and methods that belong to the class, rather than to an instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

It is only because, public static method or public static variable is not associated with any object, but the class. Though the language designer has given the flexibility of invoking them on objects, reader of the code would be confused whether those are static variable/methods or instance methods/variables. So readability is the reason behind  asking the developers to invoke them on classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to access static members either by using the class name notation or by accessing using an object. It is not recommended to use the object notation since it can be very confusing.

```
public class TheClass {
    public static final staticValue = 10;
    public static void staticMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello from static method");
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        TheClass obj = null;

        // This is valid
        System.out.println(obj.staticValue);
        // And this too
        System.out.println(obj.staticMethod());

        // And this is also valid
        System.out.println(((TheClass)null).staticValue);
        // And this too
        System.out.println(((TheClass)null).staticMethod());

    }
}
```

It is much clearer if the static methods and variables are called with the class name notation.

Answer (score -1):

static variable belongs to the class and not to object(instance).
A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object.
it saves space not having to have variables for the same data for each class.

```
Syntax : <class-name>.<variable-name>

public class AA{

 static int a =10;


}
```

**You can call**

```
System.out.println(AA.a);
System.out.println(aObject.a);
```

There is no differen between two calling but maintain coding convention to keep more readbale