# invoke static method using this.Method vs ClassName.Method

Tags: java

One static method Func() is defined within a class. Invoking it in this.Func does not have compile error. Also, invoking static method against an object doesnt have any disadvantage. And make calling method simple since the class name might be difficult to spell. 
  Not sure, this is a good java coding way.

Comment: So you want to use `this.Func()` just because you don't have to spell class name? Great. How would you call the method from outside the class then?

Comment: Using `this.Func()` certainly isn't easier to type than just `Func()`.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174573/java-convention-on-reference-to-methods-and-variables

Comment: You can't call that method with `this` in a static context..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/is-calling-static-methods-via-an-object-bad-form-why

Comment: This is a really bad java coding way.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling a static method, you shouldn't use an instance, even though it compiles because it is plain confusing.  Consider the following.

```
Thread t = new Thread( ... );
t.start();
t.sleep(1000);
```

The last method doesn't operate on the thread `t` as it is static. It causes the *current* thread to sleep.

```
Thread t = null;
t.yield(); // compiles and runs even thought `t` is null.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use this with class name to maintain the readability because if someone wants to debug in your code, so he has not to go back and see your variable declaration that it is marked as static or not, so it is better to use with class name so no need to go back and think about it

ya it is the possible duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/… –](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174573/java-convention-on-reference-to-methods-and-variables)

Comment: @SecureFish is this makes sense to you my friend