# java invoke static method from instance method & from static class call

Tags: java, static

I have a class with static method which will be invoked from same class method and from other class using Class.staticmethod. something like this,

```
ClassA{
 public void method1(){
     ---
     ---
     method2();
 }
 public static void method2(){
    ---
    ---
 }
}

ClassB{
  public void call(){
    ClassA.method2(); //i have to invoke through static method.
  }
}

public void main(...){
 ClassA obj = new ClassA();
 obj.method1();
}
```

Is the code follow the standard (Section 10.2 of Java conventions)? or i should invoke ClassA.method2() in classA method1. Please dont say this is a duplicate, I have looked at the other questions, they don't talk about this scenario.

- [invoke static method using this.Method vs ClassName.Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146254/invoke-static-method-using-this-method-vs-classname-method)
- [Java convention on reference to methods and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174573/java-convention-on-reference-to-methods-and-variables)

Comment: [Funnily enough, the conventions you mention *explicitly* mention that the usage you describe is OK.](http://javascript.crockford.com/javacodeconventions.pdf)

Comment: `ClassA::method1` is useless if its job is to call  `ClassA.method2()`. You should remove it and always use `ClassA.method2()`.

Comment: @Happy that's just code example to show OP's intentions.

Comment: @Makoto I agree - it is funny, since it actually really bad coding style ;-)

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. Is it "how should I call a static method? from an instance or just by itself? If so, the answer is it depends on your situation, but in the situation you presented you should call it directly.

Comment: Your example code is consistent with the Java coding conventions document.  However, although those conventions are widely adopted, it's incorrect to call them a "standard".

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah you probably right but never forget that some beginners can find this question, so it's valuable mentioning that.

Comment: @Happy, method1 has some lines for code and then it invokes method2. i have just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/javacodeconventions.pdf) state (thanks to [Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354)), you should refrain from using an object reference to call a static method. That means, do **not** do this:

```
someObject.staticMethod();
```

Instead, use the Class name like this:

```
SomeClass.staticMethod();
```

Of course, if you are calling the static method from within that class it is ok (and probably preferred) to do this:

```
staticMethod();
```